# Issue with connecting M1 Mini to LG 77” CX

Tags: mac, mac-mini

Connecting m1 mini to LG 77” CX via USB-C to HDMI. Unable to detect my keyboard and mouse. Even tried plugging peripherals directly into USB-C ports on mini. Confirmed peripherals worked with my iMac. Also returned Mini and brought another home per AppleCare support recommendation.[image: picture of issue]

Comment: You don’t need a display connected for the mouse and keyboard to work. This can be simplified dramatically by editing in what type of mouse or keyboard you have and removing the display.

Comment: Not sure I understand. You've plugged in a display via HDMI, and you want USB peripherals to work when attached to the monitor? I don't think HDMI supports peripherals. Presumably you've plugged the peripherals directly into the USB-A ports (not USB-C) -- and they don't work there either, but they do work on an iMac. (which model?). Also, what keyboard and mouse?